# C# Work out time and date with timezone difference

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, timestamp

I am running into a little issue, I am connecting to the Pokerstars.com datafeed to fetch updates on scheduled poker tournament info (https://www.pokerstars.com/datafeed/tournaments/all.xml)

I then parse the information and store it in a listView in my Winforms application, however I need to work out the correct time including local timezone differences. I know the Pokerstars server runs at -05:00 but my problem is converting it to the correct time for the particular user of my application.

Could someone work out the code to convert it to local times for that user, so the correct start time is displayed. Here is the code I use to read the XML file:

```
    private void LoadAllTournaments()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml("http://46.101.5.145/Feeds/all.xml");

        ListViewItem item;

        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["tournament"].Rows)
        {

            StartDate = dr["start_date"].ToString();

            if (dr["play_money"].ToString() != "true")
            {

                FPPFee = Convert.ToInt32(dr["fpp_fee"]);

                if (FPPFee == 0)
                {

                    if (dr["buy_in_fee"].ToString() != "$0 + $0")
                    {

                        item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { dr["name"].ToString(), StartDate.Substring(0, 10), StartDate.Substring(12, 7), dr["buy_in_fee"].ToString(), dr["prize"].ToString(), dr["players"].ToString(), dr["status"].ToString(), dr["id"].ToString()});
                        listView1.Items.Add(item);

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }
```

For the record I connect to my own server to read the files, since Pokerstars only allows people from the UK to view the XML files, so they download to my UK VPS every 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the xml, the value is provided such as:

```xml
<start_date>2015-11-02T12:50:00-05:00</start_date>
```

Therefore, you don't need foreknowledge of the server's time zone, as the offset is encoded in the data.  Simply parse the string as a [`DateTimeOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx), then use [`TimeZoneInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) to convert to the user's time zone.

```
DateTimeOffset startDate = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(
    (string) dr["start_date"],
    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
DateTimeOffset converted = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(startDate, tz);
```

In the above example `"GMT Standard Time"` is the Windows time zone identifier for London, which uses GMT (UTC+00:00) in the winter, and BST (UTC+01:00) in the summer.  You would need to know which time zone is actually applicable for your user of course.

Later in your code you were using `Substring` to pull out parts of the date - you shouldn't do that, but rather you should use a formatting string.  For example, `converted.ToString("d")` for the date, and `converted.ToString("t")` for the time. See [standard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and [custom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) formatting strings in the MSDN.

Comment: Excellent, this works great. Sorry for the late reply, I simply set the timezone using:

    TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(localZone.StandardName.ToString());

I may however simply set the timezone using user inputted settings...

Thanks again for the help ;)

Comment: Ehh, no.  If you want the local zone, use `TimeZoneInfo.Local`.  And don't assume the `StandardName` will match the `Id`.  On non-English machines they won't match, and some don't match anyway.

Comment: Also, if you will only ever use the local zone, you don't really need `TimeZoneInfo` at all, as the `DateTimeOffset` type has a `ToLocalTime` method that converts to a `DateTimeOffset` in the local zone, or a `LocalDateTime` property that has the same value in a local `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to parse the StartDate into a datetime. I don't know what the string is and you may have to parse it more precisely, but in general:

```
DateTime origDate = DateTime.Parse(StartDate);
```

And then just add or subtract hours from that to get your desired timezone. For example:

```
DateTime newDate =   origDate.AddHours(-1);
```

To subtract one hour.

Comment: Sorry, but no - you should never use add/subtract to adjust for time zone.  This is a common bad idea, usually leading to disastrous results.

Comment: Er, you may be right. But it's technically okay for non-DST countries.

Comment: Not really.  It changes the meaning of the `DateTime` value, which often leads to reinterpretation as some other value.  In other words, you're not changing the time zone, you're choosing a point in time an hour earlier.

Comment: That's right, and I assumed that DST would be the only issue why the a point in time an hour earlier would not be the same as a TimeZone with a -1 offset. Maybe when I'm more lucid I'll see more sense in your contention.

Comment: You'd have to first work out the correct offset, which yes, DST may make difficult, but there are other non-DST types of transitions to consider as well (example, [Russian 2014 base-offset changes](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/russia-abandons-permanent-summer-time.html)).  Additionally, `DateTimeKind` can mess this up, especially when the kind is `Utc` or `Local`.  The `DateTimeOffset` and `TimeZoneInfo` APIs are much safer.  Sure - it's possible if you really know what you're doing (I didn't downvote), but it's not required or recommended.

Comment: That base-offset change example is the kind of issue that I hadn't considered. I guess that means DateTimeOffset+TimeZoneInfo will adapt to these changes automatically. In that case, I wish I knew about TimeZoneInfo when I had trouble converting to and from DST timezones through DateTimes sent through WCF some months ago (it was a minor nightmare). Thanks for the lesson!